# Amazong EBS showing unreal disk usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS of 8 GB and when I've checked my free space it says I'm using almost all of it:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.2G  185M  98% /
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none               0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
udev            1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           375M  196K  375M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       394G  199M  374G   1% /mnt
```

But total size of the root is 1.6GB.
Where are the ~6GB I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the usage of the root device with

```
du -hsx /
```

This traverses your filesystem and prints out total size of all files. If the value that du print is about 7.2G then everything is right with our df output and you are really using the whole device. Then you should check the subfolders with du like

```
du -hsx /home
du -hsx /bin
du -hsx /usr
du -hsx /var
```

to find out where the data is.

**!!!WARNING!!!**

This might take a while

### Idea 2

Maybe you still have deleted files that are still in use. You can list open deleted files with

```
lsof +L1
```

The easiest way to fix this is to restart the process or the whole server.

Comment: I get 1.5 GB on the root

Comment: I added a new Idea

Comment: I get no results when running `lsof +L1`. Did you mentioned restart for the server might resolve that issue?

Comment: Thank you! apparently rebooting the server solved the issue. who knew.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my answer? Just for the points?

Comment: Can't my friend, need more reputation to do so. I would if I could :-)